# Upload an image from JSON Schema Form to GCS but the image is not displayed on GCS (Retool)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, react-jsonschema-forms, retool

I uploaded an image to **cloud storage** with a **JSON Schema Form** on **Retool**:

[image]

This is the JSON Schema:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "image": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "data-url",
    }
  }
}
```

This is the image I uploaded:

[image]

Then, I could upload the image successfully with the **query settings**:

[image]

This is the uploaded image on **cloud storage**:

[image]

However, on **cloud storage**, when opening the **"Object details"** of the image, the image was not displayed:

[image]

Moreover, when opening the **Authenticated URL** of the image, the image also was not displayed:

[image]

Are there anything missing for what I've done?

Answer (score 1):

This code for **"Upload data"** contains not just the **"Image Data"** but also other data like the **"Content-Type"**, the **"File Name"** and the **"Encoding Schemes"**:

[image]

```js
{{ form.data.image }}
```

So you need to extract only the **"Image Data"** with this code:

```js
{{ form.data.image.split(',')[1] }}
```

In addition, for **"Upload file name"**,

[image]

You can extract the **"File Name" "orangeHoney.jpg"** as well with this code:

[image]

```js
{{ form.data.image.split("name=")[1].split(";")[0] }}
```

This is the uploaded image on **cloud storage** uploaded with the 2 sets of code above:

[image]

Then, on **cloud storage**, when opening the **"Object details"** of the image, the image was displayed:

[image]

Moreover, when opening the **Authenticated URL** of the image, the image also was displayed:

[image]